# Turn multi layer dropdown from clicking to hoverable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a multi layered dropdown that goes up to three lists. I am trying to have all the lists that show up automated by hover. This is because my intention is to have an href link, right now the link only works on the third dropdown list because the click the others before is used to display the next dropdown.

i tried to add :hover in the css of the classes dropdown-menu and dropdown submenu with "display: block;" but this is not functioning and the lists still shows only when clicked.

[image: 1]

https://jsfiddle.net/nmv2d41w/1/

**DROPDOWN:**

```
<div class="dropdown p-left-15">
  <button class="filter-btn filter-btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter Coupons</button>
  <!--Category 1-->
  <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-dropdown">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" value="" href="#">C1-1</a>
          <!--Category 2-->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="test" value="" href="#">C2-1</a>
              <!--Category 3-->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href=""></a>C3-1</li>
                  <li><a href=""></a>C3-2</li>
                  <li><a href=""></a>C3-3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" value="" href="#">C1-2</a>
          <!--Category 2-->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="test" value="" href="#">C2-a</a>
              <!--Category 3-->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href=""></a>C3-a</li>
                  <li><a href=""></a>C3-b</li>
                  <li><a href=""></a>C3-c</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.filter-btn-default:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
.filter-btn.focus, .filter-btn:focus, .filter-btn:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.filter-btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.filter-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.filter-dropdown li {
  padding: 0px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.filter-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.filter-dropdown li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

html

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card my-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Bootstrap 4 Multilevel Dropdown Hover
                    <div class="options float-right">
                        <a class="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="reload"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fullscreen"><i class=" fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                                   href="">
                                    Dropdown
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 1</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                                            level 1
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">level 2</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                                    level 2
                                                </a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">level 2</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu> a:after {
  content: ">";
  float: right;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

js

```
$(".btn-group, .dropdown").hover(
  function () {
    $('>.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).addClass('open');
  },
  function () {
    $('>.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).removeClass('open');
  });
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bxuf8m13/)

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: thanks for the fix, did not realise you would require javascript for this

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a  class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Even More..</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">another level</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```